# Efficient storage of non-analysed text fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

We have an Elasticsearch index with over 100 fields. We explicitly define only a small number of the fields in our index mapping and enable dynamic mapping for everything else.

A number of the fields are chunks of markup up to 100kb in size. We only need to be able to check for their existence, so analysing them is not necessary.

What is the most efficient mapping to use for this use case?

We have so far considered the following settings for these fields (or applied as defaults for all text fields using dynamic templates):

- Keeping the field `type` as `"text"` but setting the `index_options` parameter to `"docs"` only
- Changing the `type` to `"keyword"` and defining `doc_values` as `false`

However we are unsure which strategy is the better option.

Comment: Do you need to retrieve these fields? If retrieving is not required, then you can get away with not storing them at all in ES. Just store a boolean value for each field when you are indexing.

Comment: Hi Jay, yes I can confirm we need to store them.

Comment: In that case the second option might be the best. Keyword would make sure no analysis is done. And doc_values = false would make sure no additional data structures are created to store doc values.